# Covariance issue

Tags: c#, generics

I'm facing a bit of problem with the following casting:

```
    class A 
    { 
    }

    class B : A 
    {
    }

    class C<T> where T : A
    {
        protected T property { get; set; }
    }

    class D : C<B> 
    {
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            C<A> x = new D();
            // Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `SampleApp.D' to `SampleApp.C<SampleApp.A>' (CS0029) (SampleApp)
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why this is failing since `D` is wider than `C<A>` since it implements `C<B>`, and `B : A`. Any workarounds?

Comment: By default, `C<B>` is *not* a subtype of `C<A>`. If you want covariance, you need to declare it explicitly by using interfaces and the `out` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C# 4.0, you can write the following code.

```
class A { }
class B : A {}

interface IC<out T> {}
class C<T> :IC<T> where T : A { protected T property { get; set; }  }

class D : C<B> {}

class MainClass {
    public static void Main()
    {
        IC<A> x = new D();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as long as defining and referencing the interface is allowed by the OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you nailed it. Some further reading online explained more what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's name your classes `Animal` for `A`, `Barker` for `B`, and `Dog` for `D`.

Actually `C<Animal>` is wider than `Dog : C<Barker>`. Assume you have public property `Me` of type `T` and assignment possible:

```
C<Animal> a = new Dog();
a.Me = Elephant; // where Elephant inherited from Animal
```

Oops! `Dog` is parametrized with `Barker`. Have you seen barking elephants?

You need to declare some covariant interface to allow assignment of class instantiated with more derived type argument `C<Barker>` to object instantiated with less derived type argument `C<Animal>`. You can use empty interface, like @NickW suggested, but you will not be able to do something with instance of that interface (it's empty!). So, let's do something like that:

```
interface IC<out T>
    where T : Animal
{
    IEnumerable<T> Parents(); // IEnumerable is covariant
    T Me { get; } // no setter
}

class C<T> : IC<T>
    where T: Animal
{
    // implementation
}

class D : C<Barker>
{
    // implementation
}
```

Above scenario is still impossible, but now you can

```
IC<Animal> a = new Dog();
foreach(var parent in a.Parents)
     Console.WriteLine(parent);

Console.WriteLine(a.Me);
```

Comment: I found your answer entertaining and thought provoking. However, it explains why you can't move side-to-side in the inheritance hierarchy, but not vertically. I think the problem falls here: `C<A> y = new C<B>();`. The covariance `B` -> `A` can be inferred. It feels like the compiler is being lazy, and wanting me to manually specify the covariance with `out`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that because the Generics are actualy templates and they don't act like what you want to do with them. Let me show you by this:

When you say `"C<A>"` it means a generic class by a `"parameter"` of `"A"`.
BUT
When you say `"D"` it means exactly `"D"`!

So D is not equal to a generic class by a parameter of A. As you can simply see it in the result of ToString function on both types (by using typeof).

Hope it helps

Cheers