# List<T> inheritance behaves strangely

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

I have a problem with list inheritance. It looks like a generic List with more specified members can't converted to a list with its base members.
Look at this:

```
class A
{
    public int aValue {get; set;}
}

class B : A
{
    public int anotherValue {get; set;}
}
```

You might now expect that a `List<B>` is also a `List<A>` but that's not the case.
`List<A> myList = new List<B>()` is not possible. Not even `List<A> myList = (List<A>)new List<B>()` Am I missing some basic concept here after 3 years in object oriented programming?

Comment: It is just how Generics work in .NET

Comment: It's how covariance works in .NET for generics. You have to create an intermediate interface. I had the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316838/covariance-issue) a little while ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup!

Assume you could do

```
List<A> myList = new List<B>();
```

Then assume you have a class

```
class C : A { public int aDifferentValue { get; set; } }
```

A `C` is an `A`, so you would expect to be able to call `myList.Add(new C())` as `myList` thinks it is a `List<A>`.

But a `C` is not a `B` so a `myList` - which is *really* a `List<B>` -  can't hold a `C`.

---

Conversely, suppose you could do

```
List<B> myList = new List<A>();
```

You can happily call `myList.Add(new B())` because a `B` is an `A`.

But suppose something else stuck a `C` in your list (as `C` is an `A`).

Then `myList[0]` might return a `C` - which is not a `B`.

Comment: `List<B> myList = new List<A>()` would not work because not every A is also a B. `B obj = new A()` wouldn't work either.

However, why could a `List<B>` not hold a `C` if `C : A`? I mean, I would not be able to call a `C`-specific method, but at least do anything I could do with an `A`.

Comment: @David Since you can do anything you could do with an `A`, you can put a `C` in a `List<A>`, but you can't do everything you could do with a `B` so you can't put it in a `List<B>`.

Answer (score -2):

That simple conversions is not allowed
For now use

```
List<B> lb = new List<B> { ... };
List<A> la = lb.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: "it will be allowed in c# 5.0": No, it is not allowed in C# 5.0.

Comment: `it will be allowed in c# 5.0` No it won't.

Comment: Do you have any good reference on this? C# 5 is in .Net 4.5 and therefore released...